# Dynamic Content - Triggering Refresh from within itself

Tags: xpages

I have a navigator with links/buttons and a Dynamic Content. Everything works fine, content is displayed nicely. However, I need a button inside the Dynamic Content itself to refresh the content, but it does not work. The same button located outside does refresh the content in the Dynamic Content. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me...

**test.xsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xe:navigator
        id="navigator1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicLeafNode
                label="switch A"
                submitValue="A">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:basicLeafNode
                label="switch B"
                submitValue="B">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onItemClick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xe:this.action>
                <xe:changeDynamicContentAction
                    for="dynamicContent1"
                    facetName="key_#{context.submittedValue}">
                </xe:changeDynamicContentAction>
            </xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:navigator>
    <xe:dynamicContent
        id="dynamicContent1"
        defaultFacet="key_A">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xc:ccA
                xp:key="key_A"></xc:ccA>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xc:ccB
                xp:key="key_B"></xc:ccB>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:dynamicContent>
</xp:view>
```

**ccA.xsp** (copy and update for ccB.xsp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    I am A
    <xp:link
        escape="true"
        id="link1"
        text="switch to B">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xe:changeDynamicContentAction
                    for="dynamicContent1"
                    facetName="key_B">
                </xe:changeDynamicContentAction>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:link>
</xp:view>
```